# Regular Expression RE2 Match All emails but a specific one and i can't use "?!"

Tags: regex, pcre, google-workspace, re2

i'm trying to figure out a regular expression that is supported by [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax#ascii) That will match all emails with a domain "@mydomain" , but i do want to make one exception for this rule and not match duaa.al@mydomain.com.

and the problem is RE2 syntax does not support negative lookbehind/lookahead. so i can't use (?!) to make an exception for this rule so i can't use (?!duaa.al).

the part i have that is working( matches all emails)
(?i)[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@(mydomain.com)$

but i'm not sure how to make "duaa.al" unacceptable
^([^duaa.al]) ,^(duaa.al) won't work either

Becasue i want these to match
duaa@mydomain.com
dua.al@mydomain.com

but only duaa.al@mydomain.com to not match

so is it possible to get a regular expression with RE2 with one string exception ?

Comment: Is this for use with Gsuite Content Compliance?  
If so, just use two expressions within the Content Compliance definition: 
- One with "Matches Regex" which matches your domain
- One with "Not Matches Regex" which matches your duaa.al@mydomain.com

Then set the compliance rule to "If ALL of the following match the message."

Comment: Hello , thank you for the comment sorry i check it very late